# I Don't Know How To Use/Run These Files That Are In A Github C++ Library I'm Trying To Add To My Project?

Tags: c++, github, openssl

https://github.com/gladosconn/ecdsa_cxx
I have been trying to get this library into my project (C++ using Visual Studio 2022, in Windows) because I need to use the ecdsa signature algorithm, I have copied all the files in src folder to a folder called "ecdsa" in the src folder inside my project, and I didn't do anything with the test folders (I think that I don't need them since they're just tests), but then there are these files (.ytml) ,(.txt) ,(.py), I have no idea what am I supposed to do with them or where to put them, but I sure I need them because the program isn't working, it's giving me this error `Cannot open include file: 'secp256k1.h': No such file or directory Libraries`.
Also I have done everything in the requirements section, my compiler supports C++11, and I have installed openssl, and I have CMake installed.
This is my first time using anything from Github so I'm sure what to do.

Comment: [RTFM](https://github.com/gladosconn/ecdsa_cxx#ecdsa-)

Comment: [Have you told your project where to find the headers and the library?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/vcpp-directories-property-page?view=msvc-170)

Comment: Unrelated, But Capitalizing Every Word Is Not Really A Thing.

Comment: `.py` is Python. So you also need Python. Some things in that Github project indicate to me that it was developed on Linux. Its last update was many years ago. Github is polluted with half-baked, incomplete source code dumps in some unknown state. The chance of taking a random Github project of unknown state, that was last touched years ago, uses another library that has a reputation of being very difficult to work with (OpenSSL) and successfully building it on a completely different operating system from what it was developed on -- I'm afraid the chances of success are slim to none.

Comment: @super but after 18 years is Fetch a thing?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, right-click on your project in the Solution Explorer pane. From the menu that pops up, choose the 'Properties' item. It is usually at the very bottom. A dialog box will appear.

In the left pane of the dialog box, expand the options Configuration Properties > C++ > General. Now, in the right pane of the dialog box, probably at or near the top will be an item labeled 'Additional Include Directories`. Add the full path to the folder where you copied the source files from GitHub.

You may need to explicitly add ALL the files you downloaded from GitHub into your Visual Studio project.

Try compiling again.